# How to interpret partially parallel lines in interaction plots?

Tags: anova, interaction

I am currently taking a beginners statistics course and in my current homework, I had to analyze sales figures of three different products in two environments (east coast and west coast) in a two-way ANOVA. The results give me a significant main effect for both independent variables (`p = 0.001` and `0.0001`) as well as a significant interaction effect (`p = 0.011`) with all effects being strong (all eta-squared are over 0.09, [which is considered to be high](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_ca_dshb.doc/etasquared.html)).

However, when I create an interaction plot, I see that the lines for two items (2 & 3) are parallel.

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

Does that have any meaning or should I still consider the lines to be non-parallel (= a significant interaction effect exists)?